# Filter a table with relation table MS-SQL

Tags: sql-server

I need to filter a table with relation table in a MS-SQL database.

I get:

```
persId  persName1   catId

 4        Hans        0
 4        Hans        51
 4        Hans        73
 5        Torleif     0
 5        Torleif     5
 5        Torleif    73
 5        Torleif    76
 6        Peter       0
 6        Peter      51
 6        Peter      73
 7        Jonas       0
 7        Jonas      16
 7        Jonas      73
```

with:

```
SELECT   distinct  tblPerson.persId
, tblPerson.persName1
, relCatPers.catId
FROM         tblPerson LEFT OUTER JOIN
             relCatPers ON tblPerson.persId = relCatPers.persId
```

---

But i need. Remove those with catId 51. And only 1 occurrence of a name and Id:

```
persId  persName1

  5         Torleif
  7         Jonas
```

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblPerson](
    [persId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [persName1] [varchar](255) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_tblPerson] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
)


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[relCatPers](
    [rcpId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [catId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [persId] [int] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_relCatPers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
)
```

Comment: What catId do you want to return for a person? The highest?

Comment: No, 76 is higher. I want only the ones that do not have 51.
And the another improvement would be that to not get the ones that have 51 and 16 etc..

Comment: What is the logic to `select 73` from the rest?

Comment: But if you want catId returned, but only one row per person, you have to tell SQL Server what catId should be returned. Do you always want catId = 73 as a result?

Comment: I dont want one with catId = 51 from tblPerson.

Comment: Ahh, so no catId returned - that makes it much clearer :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

[**Fiddle 1 demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a0dc6/15)

```
select distinct p.persId, p.persName1 
from   tblPerson p left join 
         relCatPers c on p.persId = c.persId
where  p.persId not in
       (select persId from relCatPers where catId = 51)
```

Or you can ignore `relCatPers` table and do like below

**[Fiddle 2 demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a0dc6/23)**

```
select p.persId, p.persName1 
from   tblPerson p 
where  p.persId not in
       (select persId from relCatPers where catId = 51)
```

Comment: Nice, that second query without a join! +1

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
With cte as 
(Select persId,persName1,
        row_number() over (partition by persId,persName1 order by persID) as rn
 from tblPerson 
)
Select cte.persID,cte.persName1
from relCatPers
left join cte
on tblPerson.persId = relCatPers.persId
where relCatPers.catid=51  and
rn=1
```

Comment: Last persId was wrong.
So:

With cte as 
(Select persId,persName1,
        row_number() over (partition by persId,persName1 order by persID) as rn
 from tblperson
)
Select cte.persID,cte.persName1
from relCatPers
left join cte
on relCatPers.persId = relCatPers.persId
where relCatPers.catid=51  and
rn=1

Comment: But elegant solution. Do you think performance is better than the others? With select in select etc?

Answer (score 1):

I've edited the query so it does not return a catId, as defined in your question:

```
SELECT distinct
       tblPerson.persId
       ,tblPerson.persName1
FROM   tblPerson
LEFT OUTER JOIN relCatPers ON tblPerson.persId = relCatPers.persId
WHERE  tblPerson.persId NOT IN 
       (SELECT persId FROM relCatPers WHERE catId = 51);
```

If you want to add additional catId's that should leave out persons, you can change the `WHERE` clause in the subquery to for example `WHERE catId IN (16, 23, 51)`.